# Jquery multiselect create div for each value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multi-select

I have a multiselect with more than 20 option. When the user select an option it creates a div with the name of the option selected for every item selected.
Example: user select "London" and "Paris" and it creates two div where inside is written "London" and "Paris". 
If i use $("#multiselect").val() it gives me an array, so i get all in one div.
Any idea how i can do this with Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var optionsselected = $(this).val();
  $('.divContainer').html("");
  $.each(optionsselected,function(i,x) {
    $('.divContainer').append('<div>'+x+'</div>')
  });
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var optionsselected = $(this).val();
  $('.divContainer').html("");
  $.each(optionsselected,function(i,x) {
    $('.divContainer').append('<div>'+x+'</div>')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
<option>London</option>
<option>Paris</option>
</select>

<div class="divContainer"></div>
```